# Crop an UIImageView in 9 pieces

Tags: objective-c, crop, cgrect

I need to split an UIImage in 9 buttons. Now I have nine buttons exactly occupying all the iPad screen, but I want to crop the big image in nine spaces, specifically on the buttons size/position.

Now I have this code:

```
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
CGImageRef croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);

[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

CGImageRelease(croppedImage);
```

**But**, all the buttons are showing the same image.

Anyone have an idea of what is happening and how to solve this problem (Cropping the image in nine pieces, in the X, Y, Width and Weight of the button)?

I'm really new in this.

--EDIT--

I just changed:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Thanks, Martin Pilch! :-)

Comment: Your `cropRect` likely results in the same value for each button, probably due to the fact that its origin is `(0,0)`--you should check this value using `NSLog` or the like. You'll need to make sure that the origin point for `cropRect` is different for each button. You might be able to accomplish this using a for loop or the like.

Comment: @modocache, the origin is changing normally.

Comment: Oh, my bad. When you say "all the buttons are showing the same image", which image do they show? The one set using the frame for the first button, or the last? Or neither?

Comment: Thanks for the help, @modocache. Martin gave me an right answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the original image to the buttons. Try to set it this way:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Oh, Martin, thank you! I do not know how I can not figure it out before.